# Get return value from thread, is this Kotlin code thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin

I would like to run some treads, wait till all of them are finished and get the results.

Possible way to do that would be in the code below. Is it thread safe though?

```
import kotlin.concurrent.thread

sealed class Errorneous<R>
data class Success<R>(val result: R) : Errorneous<R>()
data class Fail<R>(val error: Exception) : Errorneous<R>()

fun <R> thread_with_result(fn: () -> R): (() -> Errorneous<R>) {
  var r: Errorneous<R>? = null
  val t = thread {
    r = try { Success(fn()) } catch (e: Exception) { Fail(e) }
  }
  return {
    t.join()
    r!!
  }
}

fun main() {
  val tasks = listOf({ 2 * 2 }, { 3 * 3 })
  val results = tasks
    .map{ thread_with_result(it) }
    .map{ it() }
  println(results)
}
```

P.S.

Are there better built-in tools in Kotlin to do that? Like process 10000 tasks with pool of 10 threads?

It should be threads, not coroutines, as it will be used with legacy code and I don't know if it works well with coroutines.

Comment: This function will block when joining its thread so it will not run asynchronously. There’s no reason coroutines shouldn’t work with legacy code. But you could also use RxJava for thread pools.

Comment: @Tenfour04 not sure what do you mean by asynchronously, but they are executed in parallel, please check this example https://gist.github.com/alexeypetrushin/540ccef8419369c9d7259d6b96467453

Comment: Never mind. I missed that the function returns a function.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Java has `Executors` that doing exactly that

```
fun <R> execute_in_parallel(tasks: List<() -> R>, threads: Int): List<Errorneous<R>> {
  val executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads)
  val fresults = executor.invokeAll(tasks.map { task ->
    Callable<Errorneous<R>> {
      try { Success(task()) } catch (e: Exception) { Fail(e) }
    }
  })
  return fresults.map { future -> future.get() }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the Executors framework would be the first place I'd look, too; it's fairly standard on the JVM, and great for job queues and that sort of thing.